# How to replace file with envsubst?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I run `nano test.txt`

```
Hello $NAME
```

then `export NAME="World"`

---

- Then I run `envsubst < text.txt` it prints `Hello World`
- Then I run `envsubst < text.txt > new.txt` it saves `Hello World` into `new.txt`
- Then I run `envsubst < text.txt > text.txt` but when open `text.txt` **but it is an empty file**

How can I replace the file with envsubst?

Comment: `envsubst < text.txt | sponge text.txt`? See `man sponge`. You may need to install `sponge` first.

Comment: This question is unrelated to `envsubst`, but a general problem with redirection. You would observe the same effect with, i.e., `tr` or `sed`.